# how to extract all tables from the website below with final .jsf link with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, jsf

#Site of bank website:

http://www.fundos.caixa.gov.br/sipii/pages/public/listar-fundos-internet.jsf

I tried the code in python with pandas below

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html("http://www.fundos.caixa.gov.br/sipii/pages/public/listar-fundos-internet.jsf")
df[2].drop(3)
```

however, I was able to extract only the first table in the tab "RENDA FIXA SIMPLES"

Comment: For this site you need to learn how to scrape websites where the information change when you make an action, for example, when pressing a button or changing the tab. You will need to use the Developer tools of your browser and review the internal requests. Unfortunately, this is beyond from the goal of an SO answer. Look for example at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPe3wtA9aPM